# android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" Issue Android

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

Am using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`for switching between portrait and landscape modes. But when user opens `softkeyboard in portrait` and changes to `landscape keyboard should hide or dissappera` but its not happening with that.

Comment: orientation i understand but what is the use of keyboard hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are intercepting `orientation` without overriding `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` in your `Activity` it is normal that the keyboard remains open.

You can either

- override this method to reset the display
- or avoid intercepting `orientation` to let the `Activity` restart (in which case your `Activity` will be reinitialized and `onCreate()` will be called again)

Comment: orientation i understand but what is the use of keyboard hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in it but I think that you need to write keyboardHidden|orientation|portrait (or landscape).

Comment: here there is the list of allowed tags in the <activity> block: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html